# Dynamic Height based on the rows in Ag-Grid with vertical scroll?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using `Ag-Grid` and I want to have a dynamic height based on the number of rows, **but when it exceeds the `max-height` of the grid container it should show the vertical scroll**.

When I have a few rows it shrinks to fit the height of rows:

[image]

But When I have some more rows that exceed the `max-height` of the grid container it must show the vertical scroll: like this

[image]

I tried to achieve the mentioned feature by using `domLayout='autoHeight'` but I noticed that in this scenario, vertical scrolling will not happen.

Here is my code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-row-height-ztpznh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)

Any Idea?

Comment: share code(stackblitz)

Comment: @NarenMurali I share my code in stackblitz (updated my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with the solution to calculate the height of the grid based on its rows and then compare it with the `max-height`. If the height of the grid exceeds the `max-height`, then I set the dom layout to `normal`, Otherwise, I set the dom layout to `autoHeight`

```
private setDynamicDomLayout(): void {
    // get the rendered rows
    const renderedRowCount: number = this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount();
    const maxHeight: number = this.getMaxHeight();

    const size: {
      rowHeight: number;
      headerHeight: number;
    } = {rowHeight: 47, headerHeight:51} 
    // we can use this one in newer version 
    //this.gridApi.getSizesForCurrentTheme();

    const calculatedGridHeight: number = ((renderedRowCount * size.rowHeight)
      + size.headerHeight);

    if (calculatedGridHeight > maxHeight
      && renderedRowCount > 0
      && maxHeight !== 0) {
      this.gridApi.setDomLayout('normal');
      this.dynamicGridHeight = maxHeight;
      this.isNormalDomLayout = true;
      this.gridApi.resetRowHeights();
    }
    else {
      this.gridApi.setDomLayout('autoHeight');
      this.gridApi.resetRowHeights();
      this.isNormalDomLayout = false;
    }

    this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
  }

  private getMaxHeight(): number {
    const maxHeightStyle: string = document.defaultView
      .getComputedStyle(this.hostElement.nativeElement, '')
      .getPropertyValue('max-height');

    if (maxHeightStyle) {
      const maxHeightnumberAndunit: string[] = maxHeightStyle.split('px');
      if (maxHeightnumberAndunit && maxHeightnumberAndunit.length > 0) {
        return +(maxHeightnumberAndunit[0]);
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

And in our html we have to set `height` like this:

```
<ag-grid-angular
  class="ag-theme-balham grid" 
  [style.height]="(isNormalDomLayout) ? dynamicGridHeight + 'px': 'calc(100% - 46px)'"
  [rowData]="rowData" 
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
  [modules]="modules"
  [overlayNoRowsTemplate]="overlayNoRowsTemplate"
  (gridReady)="gridReady($event)"  >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Here is a working sample: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-row-height-ft1ezw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score -1):

Use domLayout = 'normal' or remove domLayout='autoHeight'. This will automatically give you the vertical bar you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When we use `domLayout = 'normal'` we have to set fixed height. But I need dynamic height